# Return the number of elements in a linked list recursively

Tags: java, recursion

I have the following recursive method in a class called ImageNode which is passed the head(**this** - the start of the linked list) from a class called Image.
I thought my code would recursively go through each node, increase the count then when its at the end return the count, unfortunatly not. Where am I going wrong?

```
private int countRec() {
    int count = 1;
    ImageNode node = this;

    if (node.next != null ){
        node = node.next;
        count++;
        countRec();
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: `int count = 1;` you are always setting count to 1, incrementing it and returning it.

Comment: count should not be a local variable to your method

Comment: You are resetting the count with the method call and each countRec() method will set the count to `1` set the node to `this` essencially producing the same result every time

Comment: declare count globally

Comment: I have removed int count as a local variable but i'm still getting a error - stackoverflow

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're ignoring the result of `countRec()` - and you're *iterating* within the recursive call, defeating the purpose. (You're also making a recursive call on the same object, with no parameters and no change in state... so that can't do any good.) My recursive approach would be based on a design of:

- If the next node is null, then the size of the list is 1
- Otherwise, the size is 1 + the size from the next node onwards.

So:

```
private int countRec() {
    return next == null ? 1 : 1 + next.countRec();
}
```

Now that doesn't allow for a list of length 0 of course... you probably want to separate the idea of the list from the node, in which case the list class would have something like:

```
public int count() {
    return head == null ? 0 : head.countRec();
}
```

where the value of `head` is a reference to the head node if there is one, or `null` otherwise.

Of course, this will be O(n) in time *and* space. You can get O(1) space using iteration instead of recursion, and O(1) time by just keeping the size of the list as an instance variable in the list, updating it when you need to. I'm hoping that this question was based on an educational requirement rather than real code though - in production code, you'd just use the collections provided already.

Comment: Thanks! that works perfectly, never used the ? before, bit confused as to what the ? and : are doing

Comment: @Dan_ENZ: It's the conditional operator - it checks the condition before the `?`, then evaluates either the second argument or the third. Would link to some docs, but have to get off a train now...

Comment: No worries will have a look into it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of a recursive function is it is defined in terms of itself: i.e. the count of elements in a list is equal to 0 if an empty list; otherwise it is equal to 1 + *the count of the rest of the elements of the list*.

The italicized portion of the above definition is where the function call gets made.

```
private int countRec(ImageNode node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1 + countRec(node);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive function is useful when it uses the result of the further calls to solve his problem (like an inductive step on mathematics). Your function are not using the return for the `countRec()` call for anything, and you're still trying to solve the issue without the recursion help. You can solve it by using it, as:

```java
if(node.next != null)
{
    node = node.next;
    count = countRec()+1;
}
return count;
```

Of course, since we're telling about getting your code better, you wouldn't even need to use this `node` var, just doing:

```java
private int countRec() {

    if (this.next != null )
        return (this.next.countRec())+1;
    return 1;
}
```

Hope that helps.